# SQL select statement calculating area from width and height

Tags: sql, sqlite

I need to select data from a table of images. Each image has the width and height stored, but I want to calculate the area in order to select larger or smaller images, regardless of aspect ratio.

Currently I have `SELECT * FROM image WHERE width >= 640 AND height >= 480`, but obviously this doesn't work if the image is very wide but not very high.

Is there a way to make a query more along the lines of `SELECT * FROM image WHERE [area calculated from image] >= [area calculated from query width and height]`?

Thank you.

Comment: Eh, something like `where width * height >= 307200`?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko That easy?!

Comment: yes, you may put a *formula* if you want

Comment: I would use `width * height >= 640*480`.  Much easier to understand.

Comment: @GordonLinoff I actually just did that, I agree, it makes more sense that way!